# Cannot reference another php file in another folder

Tags: php

So I have no idea what the problem is here

My file tree looks something like this

```
 -Main
   -age
     -index.php
   -test
     -index.php
```

So I'm calling this from `index.php` in `test` and it doesn't work.

```
<?php 
echo file_get_contents("../age/index.php");
?>
```

I get the error saying the file doesn't exist

Comment: ***So I'm calling this from index.php in test and it doesn't work.*** from where? What directory is the current directory using getcwd? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: @Andreas He is doing this from `test` dir in `index.php` file.

Comment: Yes, but what is the working directory. Not from what file. If the working directory is the main folder then that code will go back one step then not find /age/

Comment: Check either your file at the age directory is not written correctly or the directories test and age are not at the same level.

Comment: Use this `<?php 
  $my_host =  "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $file_path = '/Main/age/index.php';
  $my_host_with_path = $my_host.$file_path;
  echo file_get_contents($my_host_with_path);
?>`